# Get all instances of a record from a firebase query and show them as a list along ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'm currently working on a billing list using firebase and angular.

The list consist of data that shows information for a specific month, please see image[image]

Querying the list was no problem, however, I have an Arrears column on which, I need to check if they have an existing billing from other months e.g June, July, August and sum it up to show it as well, I could query and get all the other months that but the problem is I don't know a correct way on merging it the on the current observable, I know this is more of a front-end manipulation but I'm getting a dead end on this one. I tried combining them but the "Arrears" value doesn't match for each respective information on the list.

Here's my code

```
// Get the list of customers for the specific month

    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('ledger',
      ref => ref
      .where('customerZone', '==', Number(this.customerZone))
      .where('customerStatus', '==', this.customerStatus )
      .where('customerBillMonth', '==', this.qxBillMonth)
      .orderBy('customerSequence','asc')
      .where('customerPA', '==', true)
    )
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
    this.customers.subscribe(
      (data) => (this.customerList = (data),
        console.log(this.customerList)
        )
      
    )


// Get Arrear months
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.customerList.length; i++) {
      this.arrearsCollection = this.afs.collection('ledger',
      ref => ref
      .where('customerName', '==', this.customerList[i].customerName)
      .where('customerNo', '==', this.customerList[i].customerNo)
      .where('customerStatus', '==', this.customerStatus )
      .orderBy('customerSequence','asc')
      .where('customerPaymentStatus', '==', false)
    )
    this.arrears = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
    this.arrears.subscribe(
      (data) => (this.arrearsList = (data),
         //arrears reduce logic goes here
        )
      
    )
  }
```

and this is how I present my data for the list

```
   <div class="cListInfo" *ngFor="let customer of customerList">
       <div class="c11">
          {{customer.customerSequence || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c12">
          {{customer.customerName}}
       </div>
       <div class="c13">
          {{customer.customerNo || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c14">
          {{customer.customerPrevious || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c15">
          {{customer.customerPresent || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c16">
          {{customer.customerPrevious || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c17">
          {{customer.customerWaterBillSum || 0}}
       </div>
       <div class="c18">
           <!--Arrears goes here ->
        </div>
        <div class="c19">
           {{customer.customerPaymentAmount || 0}}
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, by doing the for loop inside the subscription itself and putting another iterable on the on ngFor.

```
      this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('ledger',
      ref => ref
      .where('customerZone', '==', Number(this.customerZone))
      .where('customerBillMonth', '==', this.qxBillMonth)
      .orderBy('customerSequence','asc')
  
    )
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
    this.customers.subscribe(
      (data) => {this.customerList = (data)
      for ( let i = 0; i < this.customerList.length; i++) {
        this.arrearsCollection = this.afs.collection('ledger',
        ref => ref
        .where('customerName', '==', this.customerList[i].customerName)
        .where('customerNo', '==', this.customerList[i].customerNo)
        .where('customerPaymentStatus', '==', false)
        .orderBy('customerSequence','asc')
        )
          this.arrears = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
          this.arrears.subscribe(
            (data) => (this.arrearsList = (data)) 
        )
      }
      }
    )
```

and in the HTML

```
 <div class="cListInfo" *ngFor="let customer of customerList; let arrears of arrearsList;let i =index;">
                    <div class="c11">
                       <b>{{i+1}}.</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c12">
                        {{customer.customerSequence || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c13">
                        {{customer.customerName}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c14">
                        {{customer.customerNo || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c15">
                        {{customer.customerPrevious || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c16">
                        {{customer.customerPresent || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c17">
                        {{customer.customerCUM || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c18">
                        {{customer.customerBilling | number : '1.2-2' || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c19">
                        {{arrears.customerBilling | number : '1.2-2' || 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="c110">
                        {{customer.customerBilling | number : '1.2-2' || 0}}
                    </div>
                </div>
```